# Xcode Open push notification and go to a view

Tags: ios, push-notification

3.1 to build my app,I am able to send push notifications using one signal servers, I need to enable the user receiving a push notification to open my news page as a view controller or a web page by taping the notification when received..can you help..?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch info from a received push notification in methods `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` or `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. Based on that info you can decide which view controller you need to show

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
```

Here you can fetch it from the `launchOptions` parameter. This method will be called when you launch your app by tapping the notification.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

Here you can fetch it from `userInfo` parameter. This method will be called when your app is running or if you bring it to the foreground by tapping the notification